# How to find the direction of the magnetic field in a toroidal inductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electricity, electric-circuits

[image]

I drew sort of a picture down below (although the cell is supposed to be an ac supply). I don't understand which direction the magnetic flux?

This is because, the current-carrying wire has individual magnetic fields (using the right hand grip rule) and so I am confused with how you tell in which direction the magnetic flux in the soft iron core is going in.

I understand that the magnetic flux changes direction because of the ac supply (the current is constantly changing direction and so the magnetic flux will change direction) but I don't understand how the other coils are linked.
The magnetic flux is oscillating through the first coil connected to the ac supply and this oscillating magnetic field causes the magnetic flux in the coil to oscillate. This then causes the magnetic flux within the 2nd and 3rd coil to oscillate which then produces an emf within the coils.

Oh so maybe the direction is constantly changing...?

Comment: Your sketch needs to be more clear in indicating which side of the powered loop s on the front.

Comment: I also cannot tell which direction the wires are wound. One end of the wire should be drawn **clearly** on the top and the other end **clearly** on the bottom.

Comment: Okay! I will try to find a picture of what I have described.

Comment: [This may](http://relayman.org/temp/snip_from_phasing_class.pdf) help you.

Comment: Ah! Yes it did. Thanks very much!

Comment: Much better. Is it clear to you in this picture that the flux in the core is counter clockwise?

Answer (score 2):

If you point your right hand thumb in the direction of positive current flow, your fingers will wrap around in the direction of the magnetic field.

Comment: For a coil it is easier to wrap your right hand fingers in the direction of current flow, so you’re thumb will point in the direction of flux through the core.

Comment: That is true, but I prefer to keep the number of right hand rules to a minimum.

Comment: That is a good point.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply alternating current to the terminals of coil the flux also changes direction and instantaneous flux also can be found by using right hand rule.